# How can I search for only folders (while iterating through a directory using boost)?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, directory

How can I search for only folders (while iterating through a directory using boost)? How can I filter my results to get only folders?

I have tried by the names but folders can be strangely named to appear as if they have extensions and I have to deal with that as I am trying to robustly search through a very big and very messy directory (I am not allowed to simply clean it up, it must be searched and filtered as-is...)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question does not include what has already been tried, so if not already done, then the following would definitely help:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html#Directory-iteration

Directory iteration plus catching exceptions - (tut3.cpp)

Boost.Filesystem's directory_iterator class is just what we need here. It follows the general pattern of the standard library's istream_iterator. Constructed from a path, it iterates over the contents of the directory. A default constructed directory_iterator acts as the end iterator.

The value type of directory_iterator is directory_entry. A directory_entry object contains a path and file_status information.  A directory_entry object can be used directly, but can also be passed to path arguments in function calls.

The other need is increased robustness in the face of the many kinds of errors that can affect file system operations. We could do that at the level of each call to a Boost.Filesystem function (see Error reporting), but it is easier to supply an overall try/catch block.

tut3.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  path p (argv[1]);   // p reads clearer than argv[1] in the following code

  try
  {
    if (exists(p))    // does p actually exist?
    {
      if (is_regular_file(p))        // is p a regular file?   
        cout << p << " size is " << file_size(p) << '\n';

      else if (is_directory(p))      // is p a directory?
      {
        cout << p << " is a directory containing:\n";

        copy(directory_iterator(p), directory_iterator(), // directory_iterator::value_type
          ostream_iterator<directory_entry>(cout, "\n")); // is directory_entry, which is
                                                          // converted to a path by the
                                                          // path stream inserter
      }

      else
        cout << p << " exists, but is neither a regular file nor a directory\n";
    }
    else
      cout << p << " does not exist\n";
  }

  catch (const filesystem_error& ex)
  {
    cout << ex.what() << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (is_directory(p)) // is p a directory?` This is exactly what I was looking for, feels silly not to have found it but I am very new to boost. The other error checks could also be useful. Thanks!